# Android Studio menu and Usability Questions for a Gradle project

Tags: android, android-studio

Android newbie here, had some quick questions:

How can you tell if your project is launching on a device?

Where do you see compilation errors? Just the event log?

How do you stop a project running on the device, and how can you tell if its stopped?

Comment: Use `Console` and `LogCat` for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can you tell if your project is launching on a device?

Logcat can tell you if the process is running, and the log output from your app (if it launched).

> Where do you see compilation errors? Just the event log?

Well, pretty much, not sure where else you'd expect to see them. Runtime errors get back to you via Logcat, compilation errors stay in the event log.

> How do you stop a project running on the device, and how can you tell if its stopped?

Not entirely sure if it's possible to do via Android Studio, but you can always just kill the process from ADB.

Answer (score 0):

Logcat is the best place to see compiling error. 
 
You can easily access all Logs also on a tool supplied by Android Studio called: Android Device Monitor.  
 
For seeing if it has installed, there is a console called adb log where it tells you if installation was successful or not.